# shallow copy of arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor, copy

Hello I'm making a poker game. I know this shallow copy constructor is incorrect but why is it incorrect?

```
public Deck() {
    cards = new ArrayList <Card>();

    for (int type= 0; type<=4; type++){ 
        for (int value=1; value<9; value++){ 
            Card newCard = new Card (value, type); 
            cards.add(newCard); 
        }
    }

}

public Deck(Deck other) {
    ArrayList<Card> cardsCopy  = cards;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Deck(Deck other) {
    ArrayList<Card> cardsCopy  = cards;    
    }
```

Here `cardsCopy` is not related to a `Deck` instance. It is an isolated variable which will doesn't exist any longer as soon as the constructor has finished its execution.
To have a shallow copy of `other` `Deck`, you should assign to the `cards` field of the copy you are creating, the reference to the `cards` field from the `other` instance.

A shallow copy constructor could be :

```
public Deck(Deck other) {
   cards = other.cards;
}
```

But it is not a shallow copy of `ArrayList` as you ask in the title of your question since the `cards` field both in the original and in the copy refer to the same object.

To have a shallow copy constructor with a shallow copy of `ArrayList`, you could do :

```
public Deck(Deck other) {
   cards = new ArrayList<Card>(other.cards);
}
```

or use the `clone()` method  defined in `ArrayList` :

```
public Deck(Deck other) {
   cards = other.cards.clone();
}
```